# Checking if a number's reverse is equal to the number

Tags: javascript

I have to make a function that tests if a certain value when reversed is equal to it's original form. 
I get a positive integer `a` and this is the code I came up with

```
   var i = 0;
   var numlist1 = [];
   numlist1 = a.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
   var numlist2 = [];
   numlist2 = numlist1.reverse();
   var final=1;
   while (i<numlist1.length) {
      if (numlist1[i] != numlist2[i]) {
         final=0;
         break;
      }
      i=i+1;
   }
   var answer="yes";
   if (final == 0) {
      answer="no";
   }
```

however when I try using it the answer gets returned as yes, even when I input a number like 211 which is not equal to its reverse.

Comment: Your code never initializes (or even declares) `i`.

Comment: sorry I forgot to include it, I have ```var i=0;``` as the first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the number to string if it's just a number.

There a simple logic for checking the number if its palindrome or not

```js
function checkreverse(number) {
  var rem, temp, final = 0;
  temp = number;
  while (number > 0) {
    rem = number % 10;
    number = parseInt(number / 10);
    final = final * 10 + rem;
  }
  return final === temp;
}

console.log(checkreverse(211));
console.log(checkreverse(212));
console.log(checkreverse(21134));
console.log(checkreverse(211343112));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses the original array, so when you run `numlist2 = numlist1.reverse();` you are reversing `numlist1` and assigning a reference to it to `numlist2`.  Instead you want to make a new identical array and reverse *it*:

```js
function checkNum(a) {
  var i = 0;
  var numlist1 = [];
  numlist1 = a.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
  var numlist2 = [];
  numlist2 = numlist1.slice();
  numlist2.reverse();
  var final=1;
  while (i<numlist1.length) {
    if (numlist1[i] != numlist2[i]) {
       final=0;
       break;
    }
    i=i+1;
  }
  var answer="yes";
  if (final == 0) {
    answer="no";
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(checkNum(212));
console.log(checkNum(2112));
console.log(checkNum(211));
console.log(checkNum(312));
```

Note that the [`.slice` method of duplicating the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value#7486130) works for arrays of primitives only.  If you were using ES6+ syntax I would have opted for the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead.  Also you may want to run your code through a linter at some point-- you're playing a bit of a dangerous game around loose equality and arguably around where you are instantiating your vars, which could lead do difficult to debug issues at some point.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is the same as what @Alexander Nied said, but with different implementation:

just change this line only:

```
numlist2 = [...numlist1].reverse();
```

EDIT:

You may also simplify the whole code like:

```
  var numlist1 = a.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
  var numlist2 = [...numlist1].reverse(); 
  var answer = (numlist1.join() === numlist2.join()) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem using the method for finding string is a palindrome or not. Here, you need to convert a number to a string first and then check string is a palindrome (reverse of a string is equal to original string ) or not.

Please try with below solution.

```
function isRevEqNum(num) {
   let str = String(num);
   const iter = [...str.toLowerCase()];
   for (let char of iter) {
      if (char !== iter.pop()) { return 'no' }
   }
   return 'yes'
}
```